# LibXML2 xmlGetProp() - No matching function

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, libxml2, xcode4.5

Hi I'm running libxml2 in XCode 4.5 and having problems with the xmlGetProp() function. 
XCode says there's no matching function for the call.

I've already added `${SDK_DIR}/usr/include/libxml2` to my Header Search Path and added libxml2.dylib in Link Binary With Libaries.

Please any help?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the second parameter is cast to const xmlChar *

ala

```
uri = xmlGetProp(cur, (const xmlChar *)"PV");
```